# Background image and div positioning?

Tags: css, html, position, positioning, background-image

I have the following structure:

```html
<div id="wrap">
   <div id="container">
       <div id="header">
       </div> <!--close header-->
       <div id="main">

… etc
```

I'm trying to display a background image that will show the full height of the image, but not force the page to scroll as a result of it but that will scroll with the page content.

I've placed a #bgimage div after the opening tag of the #container div and I've tried the following CSS:

1. position:fixed + height:100% - displays the full height of the image but doesn't scroll with the page content
2. position:absolute + height:100% - scrolls with the page but cuts off the image where the page content ends
3. position: absolute + height:1000px - displays the full image but forces the page to scroll

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set the background on the body itself. CSS3 allows you to set multiple backgrounds in case you already got one. Although this doesn't work in IE8 and before.

[edit]

Since that doesn't work in your page, try to make the bgimage div a container for your page content without specifying an exact height. Set the min-height to `100%`.

That way, it should size to the page content. It will always reach to the bottom of the window, and it won't force scrollbars when they're not needed. The min-height causes the div to fill the window in case the content is smaller than the window height.

Comment: thanks but unfortunately that won't work as I have a full screen image background slideshow (using jquery supersized) above the body so the #bgimage need to have a z-index of 2 to sit above this

Comment: Maybe you can make that a body background too. :)

Comment: just edited my reply! it's jquery supersized so it displays in it's own div

Comment: Maybe you can use `min-height` for the div, as explained in my edit of just now.

Comment: thanks I tried that but it didn't work. just crops it at the bottom of the page content. Arrggh! This is driving me mad!!

Comment: can you make a `jsfiddle` that clearly shows your problem? Apparently standard solutions don't work because of some specific features of your page. It would help if we could see and modify it 'live'.

Answer (score 0):

Use background-attachment: fixed; it will scroll with the page.

Comment: I want it to scroll with the page! I just don't want it to force the page to scroll if it extends past the page content

Comment: The property I gave you has nothing to do with forcing a page to scroll. It's probably the content in your page that is making your scrollbars appear. Use overflow: hidden, if you don't need scrollbars.